# Find and replace with newlines and carriage returns in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Task

To replace characters by carriage returns `\r`.
More specifically, I want to globally replace `\r\n\r\n\r\n` by `\r\n\r\n`

#### What I've done

- I know how to spot newline and carriage returns in VSC.
  [image]
  This also allows replacement by `\n`, but not by`\r` (being filled in literally).
  [image]
- It also doesn't help to escape the baskslash in (`\\r`)

Any ideas?

Comment: Does find: `(\r?\n){2}\r?\n` and replace with `$1` work better?

Comment: `\r` is not recognized in the replace string. `\n` is replaced by the line separator of the current file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to do.  But if you are just trying to reduce 3 consecutive linebreaks to 2 try:

Find:  `(\r?\n\r?\n)\r?\n`

Replace: `$1`

works for me.  There is no literal `\r` inserted - perhaps because the replacement is with a capture group.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with multi cursors in the current file

1. Select 3 line endings.
2. Use **Selection** | **Select All Occurences**
3. Use <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd> <kbd>Escape</kbd>